# RecyclerView is always above other views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, imageview, android-relativelayout

It seems to me that I have read all the topics on stackoverflow and have not found a solution.

The problem is that *ImageView* is always under *RecyclerView*, whatever I do, but I need to display *ImageView* on top of *RecyclerView*.

**Question:** Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**Example of right and wrong:**

[image]

**My XML:**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/bottom_style"
 android:overScrollMode="never"
 app:behavior_hideable="false"
 app:behavior_peekHeight="150dp"
 app:layout_behavior="....BottomSheetController.MyBottomSheetBehavior">

 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <....BottomSheetController.MyRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_button_close" />
    </RelativeLayout>
 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="150dp"
        app:layout_behavior="....BottomSheetController.MyBottomSheetBehavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">



 <....BottomSheetController.MyRecyclerView
                       android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />


            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_button_close" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I was hoping it would work, but unfortunately it didn't help(

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you need to wrap the content in `RelativeLayout` if not making use of a `FrameLayout` should fix your issue, remember to set `android:layout_gravity="end|top"` to position your close button on top-end. So the code looks something like below:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_style"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="150dp"
    app:layout_behavior="....BottomSheetController.MyBottomSheetBehavior">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <....BottomSheetController.MyRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|top"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_button_close" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

As for the reason, from what I believe, why RelativeLayout was showing the incorrect output was because the  the distance of views on z-axis is set based on the order they are generated. So even though the ImageView is set after recyclerview, to be on the Top, but the holders inside are generated afterwards and are therefore on top of the imageview.
If it was a simple view generated before the imageview, image would be on top as desired.

P.S.: I didn't find any documentation for this and is purely how I believe it works so if that is not the case anyone is free to correct me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help(

Comment: So, just to confirm you used ```FrameLayout``` instead of ```RelativeLayout``` and the code for Imageview was placed after the recyclerview in xml, still didn't come on top... I'll have a look, seems working to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in your adapter

```
close = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.close);
         close.bringToFront();
```